# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when fetch data with REACT from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a test to get products from a company API.

They told me:

> CORS allowed origins for local development is "http://localhost:1229"

So I set up proxy in package.json like this:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:1229",
```

And my request is :

```
const apiLink = 'https://example.com/api/checkout/products/';

    fetch(apiLink, {
        method: 'POST'
    }).then(returnedData => {
        console.log(returnedData)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

But I still get this error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled
```

Comment: In that case, you need to put your `http://localhost:3000` as a allowed host in your backend api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS allow get content from origin http://localhost:1229
so, try run development server on http://localhost:1229

using command
on linux
`PORT=1229 react-scripts start`
on windows
`set PORT=1229 && react-scripts start`

or change package.json
`"start": "PORT=1229 react-scripts start"`
`"start": "set PORT=1229 && react-scripts start"`

Comment: how can i do that bro ?
where can i set this "start": "set PORT=1229 && react-scripts start" ???

Comment: find file package.json
there will be "script" object and there will be some key like (start, build, test)

just change start value to `PORT=1229 react-scripts start` if you on linux, `set PORT=1229 && react-scripts start` if you on windows